# I want to disable radio button without using disabled attribute

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I want to make radio button `disabled`/`Unclickable`. But I am not allowed to use disabled attribute. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Why? 'Not allowed' by whom, to what end? What's the point? What's the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try !

```
 <input type="radio" onclick="return false;" />
```